# Creatable Select from react-select/creatable with API integration in react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-select, react-final-form

I have successfully integrated the creatable with react-final-form but the problem arises when i try to do an API call. I am trying to do an API call with **onIputChange** but whenever i get a response(in props), my drop down closes. Its closing up on receiving the new options. I tried it with normal select and it works fine. Here is my example code.

```
                           <Field
                            name="tags"
                            component={ ({
                                input,
                                ...rest
                            }) => (<CreatableSelect {...input}
                                {...rest}}
                            />)}
                            isMulti
                            options={sortedTagsOptions}
                            onInputChange={(x) => handleChangeTypeheadInput(x)}/>
```

The API call works fine. Only one **issue** occurs, ***the dropdown closes and goes out of focus as well as the written value goes away in the select***. If anyone has any idea on how to deal with this problem please let me know. This works fine without Field component though. Maybe mutate the form values? but having problems in that regard as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating a separate component rather than doing it all in one component.

```
const AppCreateableSelectForm = ( {
    input: {
        name, onChange, value,
    },
    className,
    incomingOptions,
    isClearable,
    isMulti,
    onFocus,
    closeMenuOnSelect,
    incomingStyle,
    isDisabled,
    placeholder,
    onInputChange,
    noOptionsMessage,
}) => {
return  <CreatableSelect
            name={name}
            isMulti={isMulti}
            onFocus={onFocus}
            closeMenuOnSelect={closeMenuOnSelect}
            options={incomingOptions}
            isClearable={isClearable}
            placeholder={placeholder ? placeholder:`Select`}
            className={className}
            isDisabled={isDisabled}
            styles={incomingStyle ? incomingStyle : style}
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}
            onInputChange={onInputChange}
            noOptionsMessage={noOptionsMessage}
            theme={theme => ({
                ...theme,
                colors: {
                    ...theme.colors,
                    primary: `#637282`,
                },
            })}
            components={{
                IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
            }}
        />
```

Some props might not be used in this code since i copied only relative code.